# Azure Devops - When doing a Pull Request alert that the branch is commits behind

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, devops

I recently started to work with Azure Devops and I previously worked with Gitlab, in terms of repos and merge requests.

In Gitlab when we do a merge request it tells us if the commit of this merge request has conflicts and if it is commits behind and how many it is behind.

In Azure Devops, when I do the Pull Request I only can see if there are conflicts and the Pull Request window doesn't show me if the branch is commits behind, which I would find convenient to have.

I know that there is a tab that shows the branches and if they are commits ahead or behind, but in this case, I want to give that information to the user whenever they are doing a Pull Request, the same scenario in Gitlab.

Is this possible to configure? Could you guys give me some guidance on this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible to configure? Could you guys give me some guidance on this?

I am afriad there is no such configure to achieve this at this moment.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps:

[image]